# const value cannot be changed using memory location

Tags: c++, memory-management, constants

I'm making some tests around c++ memory allocation.

In the following code sample I want to change the value of a const variable (= cannotBeChangedDirectly) using the memory location.

Why is it not working?

When I take a look at the memory I can see, that the value of the address (to which both variables, the const and the normal one are reffering to changes but when I print the result then the const variable still has the old result, why?)

Consider the following code sample:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int       cannotBeChangedDirectly = 10;
    std::cout << "cannotBeChangedDirectly &" << &cannotBeChangedDirectly << " cannotBeChangedDirectly =" << cannotBeChangedDirectly << std::endl;
    int* canBeChanged = const_cast<int*>(&cannotBeChangedDirectly);

    std::cout << "cannotBeChangedDirectly &" << &cannotBeChangedDirectly << " canBeChanged & " << canBeChanged << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cannotBeChangedDirectly =" << cannotBeChangedDirectly << " canBeChanged = " << *canBeChanged << std::endl;

    *canBeChanged = 19;

    std::cout << "cannotBeChangedDirectly &" << &cannotBeChangedDirectly << " canBeChanged & " << canBeChanged << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cannotBeChangedDirectly =" << cannotBeChangedDirectly << " canBeChanged = " << *canBeChanged << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "In the following code sample I want to change the value of a const variable " You can't, period. Any attempt to do so is *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cannotBeChangedDirectly` is `const` doesn't only mean you can't modify it directly, it means modifying it in anyway is undefined behavior, including modifying it through a pointer.

Comment: Ok, and why it is undefined behaviour?
The const integer "cannotBeChangedDirectly" has a memory location containing the value. If I change the value of this location the hard way (like I do in this example) then why is the cout of the memory location not showing the new value for the const integer?

Comment: @road242 The compiler sees a `const` variable, it may put it in a read-only memory, that's just one of the possible reasons. In a word, the standard says it's undefined behavior, and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @road242 It is undefined behaviour because the standard says so, it is that simple. That in turn allows implementations more freedom in performing optimizations. And usually those optimizations are the reason things go wrong when you actually invoke UB.

Answer (score 3):

Changing const´s is undefined behaviour, because:
`const` is not only that the compiler won´t let you change the variable directly,
but it allows further compiler optimization, like allocating no variable at all
and insert the value everyhere

Answer (score 2):

`const_cast` works only for memory which is not const in the first place.

```
void example(const std::string* s)
{
  std::string* edits = const_cast<std::string*>(s);
  *edits="bar";
}

std::string a;
const std::string b;

int main(){
   example(&a); //ok
   example(&b); //undefined behavior.
}
```